# A,B,C independent pairs of events, are they an independent triplet?

Tags: probability

If A and B are independent events, and A and C are independent events, and B and C are independent events does P(A ∩ B ∩ C) necessarily equal P(A)P(B)P(C)?

The question as I understand it is essentially whether the Independence of three pairs of events guarantees the Independence of all three events.

Comment: No${}{}{}{}{}{}$.

Comment: $A=C$ or $A^c=C$ could provide counterexamples

Answer (score 3):

Toss two (independent) fair coins $X_1$ and $X_2$. Let

- $A = \{X_1 = \text{Heads}\}$,
- $B = \{X_2 = \text{Heads}\}$, and
- $C = \{X_1 \neq X_2\}$.

Can you show that these events are pairwise independent but not independent?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\Omega = \{1,2,3,4\}$ be the sample space, events $A = \{1,2\}$, $B = \{1,3\}$, $C = \{1,4\}$.  Suppose the probability is uniform on $\Omega$.

\begin{align}
P(A|C) &= P(\text{choose 1 or 2 | 1 or 4 chosen}) = \frac12 \\
P(A) &= P(\text{choose 1 or 2}) = \frac12 = P(A|C) \\
P(A|B) &= P(A) = \frac12 \quad \text{similarly} \\
P(B|C) &= P(B) = \frac12 \quad \text{similarly} \\
P(A \cap B \cap C) &= P(\text{choose 1}) = \frac14, \text{ but} \\
P(A)P(B)P(C) &= \frac18 \ne P(A \cap B \cap C).
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

There is a fundamental issue that's related with degrees of freedom.  For 3 sets (i.e. events), the pairwise relationships you have 9 degrees of freedom.  Whereas for mutual independence you only have 7.  It's easy to set up examples that are not mutually independent while pairwise independent.